# form-group is not adjusting space?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In form I am using `group-form`, For some field it is not adjusting the space. Please see the image:

[image]

In the Image you can see that before  `contact` field there is one space, and contact field is not adjusting the space, why is this happening?

```
<div class="col-md-6 row" id="addWarehouseForm" ng-show='!showForm'>

    <form class="form-horizontal order-form" id="mapForm" name="mapForm">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Name:*</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">From:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">                  
        <input type="checkbox" >                    
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">To:</label>
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" >
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Contact Person:</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `col-md-6` is to small and you don't have enough space?